# Using the answer in custom field (select) to auto fill other field

Tags: custom-fields

how would I get a custom field to automatically select from a list based on the answer given in a custom field where the answer has to be selected.

Basically the user selects the Scottish local authority field from a select list (Say, Edinburgh City Council). I want a field of MSP Regions - in this case Lothian Region - to auto fill based on the local authority.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the context:

On a public or profile, develop a custom JS file to do this.

On editing a CiviCRM contact through the interface there's probably no good way to do this, other than adding custom JS in an extension.

If you're using Drupal Webform you can use the Validation Rules to show and hide fields. With some creative optioning you can get the results you need entirely through an interface.

My recommendation is the Drupal Webform.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CiviCRM Region Lookup module](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-region-lookup) You may need to tweak the code a bit for your needs.